# ¿De qué trata la técnica "bottom-up"?

Tags: algoritmos, lenguaje-agnóstico

Tengo un algoritmo escrito de manera recursiva no final en java , y me piden que también que ese algoritmo lo pase a manera iterativa con la **técnica bottom-up** . ¿Alguien me podría documentar sobre esa técnica? He buscado en otros sitios pero no me queda lo bastante claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un ejemplo de uso de esta tecnica es algo sencillo de implementar: El factorial de un numero.

Por ejemplo, podemos usar la definicion recursiva para implementar este evento:

```
int fact(int n) {
     if(n == 0) return 1;
     return n * fact(n-1);
}
```

Ese es un ejemplo de empleo de Top-Down porque vas de casos mas grandes a casos mas pequeños, sin embargo, este mismo problema puede ser resuelto utilizando el Bottom-Up de la siguiente forma:

int f = 1;

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
     f *= i;

// En f queda el factorial

Otro ejemplo que es un poco mas viable dada su estructura es el de la sucesion de Fibonnacci (1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89)

Cada numero es la suma de los dos anteriores, excepto por su puesto, los dos primeros.

La definicion recursiva (Top-Down) viene dada asi:

```
int fib(int n) {
     if(n < 2) return 1;
     return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

Si corremos esta funcion, veremos que tarda demasiado para valores pequeños como 45. Sin embargo, podemos usar la otra técnica haciendo de las siguientes dos formas:

1-

```
int F[100];
F[1] = F[2] = 1;

for(int i=3;i<=n;i++)
   F[i] = F[i-1] + F[i-2];
```

La construccion es ascendente (de abajo hacia arriba).

Otra via sería:

```
int a, b=1, c=1;
for(int i=3;i<=n;i++) {
     a = b;
     b = c;
     c = a + b;
}
```

El resultado queda en c. Espero que te sirva la idea.

Answer (score 1):

Vos tenés Bottom-up y Top-Down, 
La idea es que Top Down, es primero hacer desde lo más grande a los más chico, es decir, primero creas el método, luego las funciones más generales, y luego te vas metiendo mas para adentro, implementando cada vez funciones más específicas.

Con Bottom-up es lo contrario, desde lo más chico a lo más grande, primero creas los métodos mas específicos y particulares, y luego vas creciendo.

Por ejemplo en Bottom-up, querés crear un Reloj con alarma, entonces creas un método especifico llamado sonarAlarma() que haga esa funcionalidad, luego vas más para arriba, y te pones a pensar el método esTiempoDeSonarAlarma() que seguramente llame internamente a sonarAlamar() y así, seguís hasta llegar a tener todo terminado.